# Nextcloud database migration execute

Tags: php, frameworks, migration, database-migration, nextcloud

I want to create new table in nextcloud database so
firstly I use this command `sudo -u www-data php ./occ migrations:generate notestutorial 000` and this run succesfully and the migration file named Version000Date20210525103136.php appaer and Migration directory under my app and when execut migration with this command`sudo -u www-data php ./occ migrations:execute notestutorial 000Date20210525103136`  I get this error  `Migration step 'OCA\NotesTutorial\Migration\Version000Date20210525103136' is unknown` I don't know in deep how migrations in nextcloud work I just follow their documentation for developer